# Grails: DELETE in autobinding 1-N object arrays

Tags: data-binding, grails

In Grails you can have 1-N object relationship and you can manage the many side on the same page as the one side like this:

Author has many Books

Client side:

```
input name=authorName
input name=books[0].bookName, hidden name=books[0].id
input name=books[1].bookName, hidden name=books[1].id
```

Server side:

```
Author(params).save()
```

This will save (or update if id is not null) both the Author and the Book collection. Which is fantastic! 
But is there a way to also issue a DELETE for the book if for example books[1] no longer exists or it's id has been set to null?

Comment: You can't delete something without knowing its ID so if it has been set to null and/or doesn't exist, how would it be deleted?  Or maybe I am not understanding your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best thing is to handle this on the client. dont send the empty records and re index the new records you need to save